# How can I change currency position using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, preg-replace, currency-formatting

To format properly data from third party service, I was wondering if this regex is concise enough:

```
(([\d,.]+))(1?\sR\$)
```

to change this:

```
from 200 R$ to 400 R$ (32 products)
```

into this:

```
from R$ 200 to R$ 400 (32 products)
```

to format this output, I am using **Preg** to replace the text with `$3 $1` , as seen in http://www.regextester.com/

is this good enough or the regex is not adequate?

Comment: Also testable with this javascript: `"from 200 R$ to 400 R$ ".replace(/(([\s+\d,.]+))(1?\sR\$)/g, "$3$1");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex: `(\d+[.,]?\d*)(\s*)(R\$)`

Replacement: `$3$2$1`

---

*Test input:*

```
from 200 R$ to 400 R$ (32 products)
from 0,200 R$ to 0.400 R$ (32 products)
from 2,00 R$ to 4.00 R$ (32 products)
```

*Test output:*

```
from R$ 200 to R$ 400 (32 products)
from R$ 0,200 to R$ 0.400 (32 products)
from R$ 2,00 to R$ 4.00 (32 products)
```

---

If you want to parse also decimal numbers with no leading zero, such as `.200`, then use regex

```
(?=[.,]?\d)(\d*[.,]?\d*)(\s*)(R\$)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can definitely remove the first set or brackets

   and replace with `$2 $1`
2. What is the `1?` good for? If there is a 1 at the end of the first group that would that would be matched by `[\d,.]+`, so it is also superfluous
3. Don't take the `\s` into your capturing group, you will have then one to much in the result

So I think this would be your regex:

```
([\d,.]+)\s(R\$)
```